# Ruby RSS::Parser.to_s silently fails?

Tags: ruby, parsing, rss

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7's RSS::Parser, part of stdlib. I'm new to Ruby.

I want to parse an RSS feed, make some changes to the data, then output it (as RSS).

The [docs](http://www.cozmixng.org/~rwiki/?cmd=view;name=RSS+Parser%3A%3ATutorial.en) say I can use '#to_s', but and it seems to work with some feeds, but not others.

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'rss'
require 'net/http'

url = 'http://news.ycombinator.com/rss'
feed = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body

rss = RSS::Parser.parse(feed, false, true)

# Here I would make some changes to the RSS, but right now I'm not.

p rss.to_s
```

Returns expected output: XML text.

This fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'rss'
require 'net/http'

url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/devourfeed'
feed = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body

rss = RSS::Parser.parse(feed, false, true)

# Here I would make some changes to the RSS, but right now I'm not.

p rss.to_s
```

Returns nothing (empty quotes).

And yet, if I change the last line to:

```
p rss
```

I can see that the object is filled with all of the feed data. It's the to_s method that fails.

1. Why?
2. How can I get some kind of error output to debug a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the problem isn't in `to_s`, it's in the parser itself. Stepping way into the parser.rb code showed nothing being returned, so `to_s` returning an empty string is valid.

I'd recommend looking at something like [Feedzirra](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra).

Also, as a FYI, take a look at Ruby's [`Open::URI`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/open-uri/1.9.2/frames) module for easy retrieval of web assets, like feeds. Open-URI is simple but adequate for most tasks. Net::HTTP is lower level, which will require you to type a lot more code to replace the functionality of Open-URI.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I started debugging the code. I think the ruby rss has a few too many required elements. The channel need to have "title, link, description", if one is missing to_s will fail.

The second feed in the example above is missing the description, which will make the to_s fail...

I believe this is a bug, but I really don't understand the code and barely ruby so who knows. It would seem natural to me that to_s would try its best even if some elements are missing.

Either way

rss.channel.description="something"
rss.to_s

will "work"

The problem lies in    def have_required_elements?

Or in the
 self.class::MODELS